# accessing api for Angular application

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to access this api for an angular app I am trying to create, you can view it here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/H1bm1oaeBv3xE4sBL82U?p=preview

but it's not loading the data, anyone see what is wrong?

```
angular.module('FootballFixturesApp.services', []).
  factory('footballdataAPIservice', function($http) {

    var footballdataAPI = {};

    footballdataAPI.getFixtures = function() {
      return $http({
        method: 'JSONP', 
        headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': '613a6b6937394ae8a94d69f358f76902' },
        url: 'http://www.football-data.org/fixtures'
      });
    }

    return footballdataAPI;
  });
```

Comment: I dont think that url supports JSONP. And well you need to add callback argument as well, i.e `url: 'http://www.football-data.org/fixtures?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'` Check the network console, call comes back without wrapped data

Comment: it's hard to help you w/o API description provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to fetch the data the following way in services.js:

```
 footballdataAPI.getFixtures = function() {

        $http.defaults.headers.common['Auth-Token'] = '<INSERT AUTH TOKEN HERE>';
        return $http.get('http://api.football-data.org/fixtures?callback=JSON_CALLBACK');

    };
```

The api provider gave me the auth token for access.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this angular module with a football-data.org api factory: https://github.com/JohnnyTheTank/angular-footballdata-api-factory